# jquery mobile ajax sends both GET and POST requests

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-mobile

Here is the problem:

By default jQuery Mobile is using GET requests for all links in the application, so I got this small script to remove it from each link.

```
$('a').each(function () {
   $(this).attr("data-ajax", "false");
});
```

But I have a pager in which I actually want to use AJAX. The pager link uses `HttpPost` request for a controller action. So I commented the above jQuery code so that I can actually use AJAX.

The problem is that when I click on the link there are two requests sent out, one is `HttpGet` - which is the jQuery Mobile AJAX default (which I don't want), and the second one is the `HttpPost` that I actually want to work. When I have the above jQuery code working, AJAX is turned off completely and it just goes to the URL and reloads the window.

I am using asp.net MVC 3. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of disabling AJAX-linking, you can hijack clicks on the links and decide whether or not to use `$.post()`:

```
$(document).delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {

    //prevent the default click behavior from occuring
    event.preventDefault();

    //cache this link and it's href attribute
    var $this = $(this),
        href  = $this.attr('href');

    //check to see if this link has the `ajax-post` class
    if ($this.hasClass('ajax-post')) {

        //split the href attribute by the question mark to get just the query string, then iterate over all the key => value pairs and add them to an object to be added to the `$.post` request
        var data = {};
        if (href.indexOf('?') > -1) {
            var tmp  = href.split('?')[1].split('&'),
                itmp = [];
            for (var i = 0, len = tmp.length; i < len; i++) {
                itmp = tmp[i].split('=');
                data.[itmp[0]] = itmp[1]; 
            }
        }

        //send POST request and show loading message
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        $.post(href, data, function (serverResponse) {

            //append the server response to the `body` element (assuming your server-side script is outputting the proper HTML to append to the `body` element)
            $('body').append(serverResponse);

            //now change to the newly added page and remove the loading message
            $.mobile.changePage($('#page-id'));

            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        });
    } else {
        $.mobile.changePage(href);
    }
});
```

The above code expects you to add the `ajax-post` class to any link you want to use the `$.post()` method.

On a general note, `event.preventDefault()` is useful to stop any other handling of an event so you can do what you want with the event. If you use `event.preventDefault()` you must declare `event` as an argument for the function it's in.

Also `.each()` isn't necessary in your code:

```
$('a').attr("data-ajax", "false");
```

will work just fine.

You can also turn off AJAX-linking globally by binding to the `mobileinit` event like this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html*

Comment: I did figure out the problem before your answer - it was the `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;` so you got it right! Thanks!