# Disabling JQM ajax request and unstyled UI instead

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, asp.net-ajax

According to this post [jquery mobile ajax sends both GET and POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657460/jquery-mobile-ajax-sends-both-get-and-post-requests), I disabled my jquery post via `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false` script, but now new problem occurred and its about my page UI, as I disabled the jquery request the server response that return from first request is not user friendly at all, because jquery handle the UI of my page. Now the question is how to manage both the UI and ajax request inside my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem will solve by adding following lines to your code. It will refresh the page after each request sent. #confirm is your container where content of updatepanel placed inside it.

```
var classAssign = function(){

   jQuery('#confirm').trigger('pagecreate');
}

 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(classAssign);
```

for more information check the link https://forum.jquery.com/topic/disabling-jqm-ajax-request-and-receive-ugly-ui-instead